# sqlite3 not found en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqlite3, adb

Estoy tratando de conectarme mediante la consola al teléfono en el que tengo instalada mi aplicación para poder hacer consultas a la base de datos con SQL.

Estaba viendo un tutorial en el muestran como se realiza sin embargo no me funcionó, busqué información extra y encontré otro ejemplo que hace lo mismo, así que volví a probar pos si es que hice algo mal, pero aparece el mismo error.

Los pasos son los siguientes:

1. Ir al directorio `<sdk>/platform-tools/`
2. Escribir `adb shell`
3. Escribir `sqlite3 data/data/<package>/databases/<nombre-base-de-datos>`

Después de esto debe aparecer el siguiente mensaje:

```
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>
```

Al realizar el paso 3 obtengo el error  `sqlite3: not found`

Lo único que he notado de diferente es que después del paso 2 en los tutoriales el prompt de la consola es **#**,  `root@android:/ #` mientras que en la mía es **$**,  `HWANE:/ $` , no sé si eso tenga algo que ver.

Comment: Hola, podría ver cual es el tutorial que estas revisando?, saludos.

Comment: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/

Este tutorial, en la parte de Herramienta Sqlite3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si instalaste `Android Studio`, puedes encontrar `sqlite3`  dentro de `/platform-tools`.

Si ingresaste a `<sdk>/platform-tools/` ahí puedes ejecutar `sqlite3`, no necesitas realizar los pasos 2 y 3.

Este es un ejemplo ejecutando:

```
$ sqlite3 .help
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me funcionó, sin embargo debo hacer pull del archivo de base de datos.
En el ejemplo se ve que trabajan con el archivo original por lo que siempre estará actualizado (al menos ese entendí), pero de la manera que lo conseguí hay que hacer pull cada que se actualiza la base de datos para tener el archivo actualizado.